# Transparent Label Over Label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

hi how can i transparent Label over another label in C# ?
like this[image]

Comment: Add some information of wich kind of label's you're using and wich code you're using to place them 'on top' of each other and how you got the label border showing up.

Comment: Your images doesn't show a "transparent" label over the other one. It is fully opaque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"transparent" controls don't work well in Winform, if you need to do this short of thing, you should be using WPF, or be willing to face **lots** of pain.

But do you need to use label controls rather then drawing both bits of text in a single custom control?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom drawing in the OnPaint event of the form to place two overlapping text string or set the Label background to Transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the things that gave me problems converting an existing application from VB6 to .Net. If you make the background transparent it will look correct on the form as long as you don't overlap any existing controls. I ended up using the Graphics.DrawString Method in OnPaint event like @Barfieldmv suggests. You may want to look at this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943454)